# SAP HANA: not able to call xsjs file in HTML

Tags: html, sapui5, hana, xsjs

I had an SAP UI5 application project in which one of the pages is `product.html` and a xsjs file `getProductCat.xsjs`.

Now I made some changes in HTMl page from notepad. When I try to open in HANA's web browser the changes are there but it is not able to connect to xsjs file. However, if I try to open through browser it connects to xsjs but the changes are not there, it seems it's opening the old file.

As I am new to SAP UI5 so I think I am missing some basic step.

Answer (score 1):

Go to HANA client installation folder, run the following command line to get the help for HANA content activation:

```
C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient>regi help activate
```

**Action:**

```
activate
```

**What:**

```
inactiveObjects (all inactive objects in the current workspace)
package (all objects in a package)
packages (all objects in a package and its sub-packages)
trackedPackages (all objects in all tracked packages and their sub-packages)
object (specific objects)

Call "regi help activate <WHAT>" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

after you changed the xsjs file, did you activate it? You need to setup your workspace for the xs app. Did you?

Actually, this is not sapui5 question. This is a HANA XS application related question.

-D

Comment: Oh I am sorry I didnt realize that. How to activate it ?